# Exception handling: does more statements in a try block lead to fallible code?

Tags: exception, programming-languages, language-design

In many languages exception handling uses two or more blocks of code, `try` and one or more `catch`'s.

Exception handling in [V language](https://vlang.io/) (v0.2.4), although different syntax only allows a single statement in `try`. One of the developers motivation is that the language won't allow `try` blocks because that is "error prone".

I can't see any arguments that supports this so my question is: does allowing more statements in a try block lead to fallible code?

I see a quite big drawback with only one statement in a `try`: you may end up with more code duplication in cases where you need to attach exact same error handler. This can be alleviated to some degree by moving code to a error handling function, in some cases this is an unnecessary function declaration that you'd need to call multiple times following another and it looks quite stupid.

On a side note, one benefit with only one statement is that you don't need to declare the variable outside, this can be useful in some cases.

Comment: Exception handlers should be *as focused as possible*. You should know *where* you expect errors to happen and what errors may happen there that you're prepared to handle, and you should wrap that specific part of your code in an exception handler that can handle exactly that small set of expected errors. So, yes, the broader you make exception handlers, the more you may catch random unexpected exceptions which can lead to incorrect behaviour. Enforcing single-line handling seems a bit extreme to me though…

Comment: If you wanted to, couldn’t you just move the sequence of statements that might produce errors into a new function and call that function in the `try`? That seems essentially equivalent to multiple statements in one `try`, but you are forced to give the block a name, and pass the arguments down.

Comment: To do that `V` you mark that errors should be propagated with a `?` after each call/statement that can throw an error. Still more work than writing a try block but yes, probably the best option you have.